# How to create a spool file in plsql developer tool command window

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

After executing query in plsql developer tool command window  the query &output should be saved in spool file automatically

eg;

update im set folio_no=123 where active_flag='Y';

1 rows updated

Comment: The `spool` command is supported. What isn't working? You do need to specify a full path, or set the default path with `set spooldir`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.